# Should I write unit tests for public decorated methods in Python (ie. @property)

Tags: python, unit-testing

I believe the answer is yes but I want to read what other people have to say about this. More specifically, I am referring to @property

Comment: Are you asking if you need to test that Python language features are working?  No.  You should only need to test your own code.

Comment: For example, if I have an @property digit that returns anotherclass.anothermethod(self.digit) do i mock out anotherclass and write a unit test to make sure the digit property returns the write thing